# Replacement of 2N3822 and 2N5640 for a 0-12v adjustable power supply

Tags: power-supply, transistors, jfet

I'm trying to make an adjustable 0-12v 0-500mA power supply. I'm using the following schematic as a base (I modified the 240Ohm resistor between V<sub>out</sub> and Adj of LM317 2, and the R<sub>SC</sub> resistor):

[image]

The 2N3822 and 2N5640 are not available in my country. What could I use as a replacement? I also tried looking for the 2N5485 but couldn't find it neither.

Comment: Ups ! Sorry, forgot to mention that im using that as a base only to build a 12V and 500mA regulator. I modified the 240 resistor and the Rsc so it could fit my requirements. What schematic would you recommend to do that ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Question edited!

Comment: I need it to be regulable. It has to be from 0-12V and 0-500m :/

Comment: Right, thanks. That's beyond my knowledge, but I edited the question a bit to clarify. I hope that's okay. Now let's clean up the comments a bit, they're not useful anymore.

Comment: Those FETs are being used as current sources (or sinks). If you can work out roughly what current each of them would operate at you'd be in a better position to choose an alternative FET (or possibly even just a suitable resistor).

Answer (score 1):

Jfet's are becoming rare.  You will only need those current source jfets if you want to get to zero volts.  (If you can live with 1.25 V as V min, then...)

So what you want to do is match the zero gate (Vgs=0) current drain.  Here's a list from [digikey.](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/jfets-junction-field-effect/1377093?k=jfet)  Your job is to find out the value for the jfets in your circuit.  (I would think that they could be the same jfet??)